# Using btrfs cow functionallity to rapidly and efficiently subset large files

Tags: linux, file-management, text-editing, btrfs, deduplication

[My aim is to use btrfs cow features to subset 30GB to 300GB files into several 10GB files without producing substantial i/o nor using additional disk space. 
i.e.:

```
300GB   dna_original.fastq
10GB    dna_subset-a.fastq
10GB    dna_subset-b.fastq
10GB    dna_subset-c.fastq
```

The files in question are fastq or fasta files commonly used for DNA sequencing, they are human readable text files. Normally I would produce such a file using

`head -n x file_original | tail -n y > file_subset-1`

thereby producing substantial i/o and using additional disk space. Tools like duperemove (also i/o intensive) do not seem to recognize subsets which do not originate from the beginning of the original.

I imagine it should be possible to use `cp --reflink=always file_original file_subset-1` and subsequently remove x lines from the beginning and end of the file without writing to a new file.

Can we come up with some way to perform subsetting jobs in such a manner using btrfs?

Thanks for your consideration